# ColorPicker not editable in Form -> FormItem

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, flex4, flash-builder

*Please note the remark mentioned **WORKAROUND** at the end of this question.*

Based on a Dictionary based specification, one of my classes creates a `Form` programmatically.

Adding `TextInput` or `DatePicker` to `FormItems`s works as expected.

Unfortunately, the following code just creates a colored rectangle, not the actual picker:

```
ti = new ColorPicker();

ColorPicker( ti ).selectedColor = TAColor( _spec[ key ].value ).color;
```

and later on

```
formItem.addElement( ti );
```

The Form is embedded in a `TitleWindow` component presented using

```
PopUpManager.addPopUp(...);
```

When added to TitleWindow, it shows up correctly, within Form->FormItem not:

[image]

**I can't image, why the picker doesn't appear. Do you?**

**WORKAROUND:**

If I wrap the **ColorPicker inside a Group** things work:

```
ti = new Group();
Group( ti ).addElement( new ColorPicker() );
```

In this case, the ColorPicker appears as editable.

**Still, I'd be too happy to learn what the problem with my initial solution. Bug?**

Comment: That's definitely weird. I've tried to programmatically add a ColorPicker to a spark Form, and it does just what you explain... It does work properly though with an MX Form. I'm strongly suspecting the FocusManager.

Comment: As you explained, DateField or DatePicker work perfectly. The sources of ColorPicker are included in FlashBuilder 4.5.1. I not going to patch them. But if I would, would FlashBuilder recompile and add them to my binary?

Comment: Nope, you have the source but it's not what is used to run your apps, and, besides, you don't want to recompile thee entire framework. I suggest you to extend the component and try to patch it. I've tried this by myself, but couldn't find any workaround...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A DateField (which extends ComboBase like ColorPicker) behaves properly in a spark Form. But in the ColorPicker, the mouse down handler of the button never gets called. I think that maybe the skin part that handles the mouse clicks (it must be a button) is not properly dimensionned, and the result is it is not shown. I've come to this conclusion because within an mx Form, the ColorPicker doesn't display as it does when it is added to the regular displaylist...

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

In the code you've provided, you never add the colorPicker as a child to any parent container; as such it will never show up anywhere.

You probably need to do something like:

```
formItem.addChild(ti );
```

[or for a Spark formItem]:

```
formItem.addElement(ti );
```

I'm confused as to why you're seeing a rectangle.

Comment: Correct! But in fact, I do add the FormItem. Since the this FormItem is only one of several, the code is below the above printed code. Yes, it does the formItem.addElement();